Variable display format
Stata receives my commands for the justification of a string variable named make on the right (format make %18s) and left (format make %-18s). This reception results from the ‘properties’ table. Nevertheless, the change does not appear in the database. How can I make the format change (right or left justification) of the variable appear within the database (namely at the column of the variable make)?
I tried to make the change appear by typing in the command edit.

The allusion is presumably to
sysuse auto, clear

and its make variable. Such format changes are more visible with list.
Consider
. sysuse auto, clear
(1978 automobile data)

. clonevar make2 = make

. format make %18s

. format make2 %-18s

. list make make2 in 1/10

     +-------------------------------+
     |          make   make2         |
     |-------------------------------|
  1. |   AMC Concord   AMC Concord   |
  2. |     AMC Pacer   AMC Pacer     |
  3. |    AMC Spirit   AMC Spirit    |
  4. | Buick Century   Buick Century |
  5. | Buick Electra   Buick Electra |
     |-------------------------------|
  6. | Buick LeSabre   Buick LeSabre |
  7. |    Buick Opel   Buick Opel    |
  8. |   Buick Regal   Buick Regal   |
  9. | Buick Riviera   Buick Riviera |
 10. | Buick Skylark   Buick Skylark |
     +-------------------------------+


The suggestion worked correctly. Evidently the variable ‘make’ only allows the justification to be displayed with ‘list’.
I have a doubt: is it possible to export the file with the desired justification (left or right)?

The display format will be saved with any .dta file but not I think otherwise.
